Trouble Persisting Session State Across Redirects in Go HTTP Server for OAuth Implementation with React Client
I'm developing a web application in Go that utilizes the net/http package for handling HTTP requests. I have a login system set up where, upon successful authentication, the user is redirected to an authorization page. However, I'm encountering issues with persisting the session state across redirects.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if dumpVar {
        _ = dumpRequest(os.Stdout, "login", r)
    }

    //Start store
    store, err := session.Start(r.Context(), w, r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    //If form is submitted (POST request)
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        //Pares form data
        if r.Form == nil {
            if err = r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
        }

        username, password, ok := r.BasicAuth()
        if !ok {
            w.WriteHeader(500)
            w.Write([]byte("Could not read username and password from header"))
        }
        log.Printf("username in /login: %s", username)
        log.Printf("passsword in /login: %s", password)

        userID, err := srv.PasswordAuthorizationHandler(context.Background(), "ID", username, password)
        //userID, err := srv.PasswordAuthorizationHandler(context.Background(), "ID", r.Form.Get("username"), r.Form.Get("password"))
        log.Printf("userID in /login: %s", userID)

        if len(userID) != 0 {
            // Store logged-in user ID in store
            store.Set("LoggedInUserID", interface{}(username))
            //store.Set("LoggedInUserID", r.Form.Get("username"))
            err = store.Save()
            log.Printf("session in /login: %v", store)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            // Redirect to authorization page
            w.Header().Set("Location", "/authorize")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
            return
        } else {
            tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(conf.Config.PathHtml + "login.html")
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
            return
        }
    }

    //Render login HTML page
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(conf.Config.PathHtml + "login.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func authHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if dumpVar {
        _ = dumpRequest(os.Stdout, "authHandler", r) // Ignore the error
    }

    // Start store
    store, err := session.Start(nil, w, r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("session in /authorize: %v", store)

    // Check if user is logged in
    if _, ok := store.Get("LoggedInUserID"); !ok {
        // If not logged in, redirect to login page
        w.Header().Set("Location", "/login")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    // Render authorization HTML page
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(conf.Config.PathHtml + "auth.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

The issue arises when I redirect from the login handler to the authorization handler. Despite starting a session in the login handler and setting a value (LoggedInUserID), it seems like the session data is lost during the redirect, as the authorization handler can't detect the user's logged-in state.
I'm trying to implement OAuth for authentication, and I have a React client that initializes the OAuth flow. After successful authentication with the OAuth provider, the user is redirected back to the authorization page (/authorize).
I've tried using different session storage mechanisms (e.g., cookies, memory-based sessions), but none seem to resolve the problem. Is there something I'm missing in my implementation, or is there a better approach to persisting session state across redirects in Go?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
